# Accessing red5 server outside the localhost

Tags: video, red5, video-recording

I am new on red5 server so I stuck in. I am trying to record videos from webcam and save them in to my server. To do this, I installed red5 to my server. In addition, I also downloaded red5recorder and put it into my webapps folder. But there is any information about its implementation details. Whatever. So I go on with Red5 SimpleRecorder tutorial.

Everything works fine when I tried in my server, but there is a problem when I try to connect to server from other computer to record a video. Actually, video recording is handled but the recorded video is not uploaded to the server. When I work in localhost it works fine, but from outside I couldn't be able to record or upload the video.

I change the red5-web.properties document, and set virtual host to my server's IP but it again only works in localhost. What could be the reason? Is it about file permissions? or what could it be?

Kind regards,
Can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using red5recorder or (any other demo). It seems the rtmp server is set to rtmp://127.0.0.1:/red5recorder in the red5recorder.swf. You need to search for the following in src/red5recorder.as:

```
if(Application.application.parameters.server!=null) 
    myRecorder.server= Application.application.parameters.server;
```

and change that to:

```
if(Application.application.parameters.server!=null) 
    myRecorder.server= "rtmp://your-server-ip/red5recorder";
```

Then compile from source.

EDIT:

You could be better of changing the Recorder.as (src/classes/Recorder.as) file instead with all the parameters mentioned there.

```
server:String="rtmp://127.0.0.1/red5recorder/";
```

Then compile the source and make the new .swf.

As it turns out there are flash parameters that you can pass from html to swf.
Check here : http://www.red5-recorder.com/params.php